# Typescript mix unknown with known properties and one of those being a function throws "This expression is not callable."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to use typescript to mix known and unknown properties. I am using this in a react context and here is what I roughly have...

```
interface IFoo {
  [key: string]: IClient | ICompany | IUser;
}

interface IBar {
  set: (arg0: IClient | ICompany | IUser) => void;
}

type FooBar = IFoo | IBar;

const ItemContext = createContext<FooBar>(null);

export function useItems() {
  return useContext<FooBar>(ItemContext);
}

export function ItemProvider({ children }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<FooBar>(null);

  function addItem(resource: IClient | ICompany | IUser) {
    setItems({
      ...items,
      ...{ [resource.id]: resource },
    });
  }

  return (
    <ItemProviderContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...items,
        set: addItem,
      }}
    >{children}</ItemProviderContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

When consuming and trying to use set like so:

```
export function useRouter() {
  const items = useItems();

  function test(clientObject: IClient) {
    items.set(clientObj); <-- error thrown here
  }
}
```

I get:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'IClient | ICompany | IUser | ((arg0: IClient | ICompany | IUser) => void)' are callable.
    Type 'IClient' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Is there a way to mix known and unknown properties in typescript?

Comment: Can we get a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I don't know how you're defining and consuming your context, or what your interfaces are.

Comment: I added the small bit of defining the context. Problem really isn't in that. Its the typescript issue. I want to use known properties with unknown ones. The known property is a type of function.

Comment: I think you forgot the last part of my comment. We're still missing the definitions for the interfaces: `IClient`, `ICompany`, `IUser`, `Client`. I know it is a TypeScript issue, but the problem is **we can't reproduce your problem** without the relevant code. .

Comment: I noticed if I do this: `(items.set as (arg0: IClient) => void)(client);` it will work but that seems hacky.

Comment: FWIW I ended up patching your code to get a MRE myself. You could move the "unknown" properties into its own, known property, to separate the unknowns and knowns: https://tsplay.dev/w6xYYm

Comment: I thought about that too and I think that might be the only way to do it.